# Turning a workflow on and off via apex?

Tags: apex, metadata

I have a power user who reviews a bunch of workflow notifications. When she goes on vacation she wants to remove herself from the notifications and then add herself back. How Can I create an interface so she can do this?

Comment: sheesh -- why not just put a rule in her Inbox to filter out the notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do this with much Apex.  I'd use a hierarchical custom setting that you check on in the workflow formulas.  Either that or put the target of the workflow to a queue that the person has access to.

But why would this be a thing?

Answer (score 0):

If she is the only recipient of the workflow then you can think of deactivating it during her absence but if there are other recipients as well then it has to be something on the user level.

If the prior is true , I would suggest add one Custom Label to the workflow and change it during her absence so that the workflow won't fire. If she is a power user, I believe she must have access to Custom Label which she can edit herself.

However this works in one or two scenarios. If you have similiar use cases, I would suggest design something using Metadata API or even better Tooling API